# Angular 7 start page location

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm, building an ASP.NET Web API (.NET 4.6, not Core) application with an Angular 7 front-end. When I run ng build or ng serve, Angular will generate all the output files, including the **index.html** start page, to whatever folder I have configured in my **angular.json** file, under **outputPath**. **I also have an index.html file in the root folder of my ASP.NET project**, which will be my start pae in IIS. Question is, is there a way for me to tell Angular use that file instead, so it "injects" the js references there, and not in the index.file under the folder configred in outputPath?

In other words, when I use **ng serve** and I go to localhost:4200, my guess is that Angular by default goes to the folder configured in outputPath, and uses index.html as the start page. Of course, when I run the site through IIS, it will go to the index.html file located at the site´s root (no the one configured in outputPath), and that one doesn´t have the js references (runtime, vendor, main, etc), nor will it have the CSS it injects for things like Bootstrap or FontAwesome. So, is there a way to tell angular to use my index.html file to inject all those references, instead of using the one it creates under outputPath?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually u should use index.html in outputPath. And for develop mode (by 'ng serve') and for production mode (by IIS).
You should configurate IIS to work with index html in output path (/dist folder by default).
When you use "production mode" you can check your application by IIS.
When you use "ng serve" you can can develop your application.
When application will be ready you can copy all your /dist folder and its subfolders and bring in to live web-server.
Hope it is help.

Comment: Thanks for replying, let me see if I get it correctly: In dev mode, I'll just use ng serve, as usual. When I deploy to IIS, I should copy the contents of by dist folder to my Web site's root, and it should work. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. And additionaly you have third option: If you want check your application in prod mode you can configuration your IIS to '/dist folder'. 1) When you develop use ng serve and 'localhost:4200', 2) when you build with prod mode use 'localhost:5013' (for example). 3) For live you can replace all files to other place.